# How do you parry damage?

Tags: bunny-must-die

Sometimes you appear to be able to completely negate damage your way when you press... some buttons at... some point. Overall controls in this game seem to be kind of mystery meat, but I'm not asking about controls in general.

Knowing how to parry reliably would be very useful, especially when dealing with spikes. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block/defend/parry, you have press **any direction button** to block damage. Using "forward" can be helpful as your finger is probably already on the button, and up can be helpful to bound straight up from aerial parries. Block slightly **before** the hit lands. I first learned this from [Quadrapod's Bunny Must Die walkthrough on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/944518-bunny-must-die-chelsea-and-the-7devils/faqs/51486) which has a little info (search for Defend).

After a successful block on the ground, Bunny will stop immediately and raise her fist during the parry. After a successful block in midair Bunny will  somersault *straight* up (maybe half normal jump height?) and you can control her during the jump. Since she does a somersault you can't stomp on enemies from a parry. You can parry again even in midair.  A surprisingly satisfying ching! sound also plays with a successful parry.

The window for parrying is pretty short, even I can't do it flawlessly. Factor in your reaction time and press the button just a little before you think Bunny will take the hit. Enemies that shoot fireballs are a good place to practice this, once you have that down, try it on spikes.

You can block anything that causes damage in the game; enemy projectiles, enemy's bodies, fire, and yes, spikes. You'll really want to learn how to block spikes, as they deal extreme damage and are pretty predictable.

Enemy projectiles (except thick lasers and certain boss attacks) will be erased after a successful block (just as if you had taken the hit) and **spikes will be destroyed.** You can even, amusingly, walk into and block spikes to just walk through whole pits of spikes if you're good/lucky.  Spikes regenerate, so keep moving.

Comment: Actually, you should be able to parry by pressing in any direction - the forward direction is just helpful for not losing distance when walking. I personally prefer pressing Up when doing a standing guard. Parrying to bounce is also extremely important for a lot of the low-% puzzles.

Comment: @GraceNote the guide says the direction you're facing but come to think of it I'm pretty sure I can do it with down too. I'll have to try it tonight to be sure. I should have figured you'd be familiar with BMD